# Options request before Post Requests

Tags: ajax, post

Can anyone please explain in detail that why ajax uses OPTIONS request before POST request while using headers in APIs.

Is there any way to bypass the OPTIONS request, I just want POST request on my server.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using **Axios**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

```
axios.get( url,
{ headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"} } ).then( res => {
if(res.data.error) {
} else { 
doAnything( res.data )
}
}).catch(function (error) {
doAnythingError(error)
});
```